# Request.IsAuthenticated still true after IIS restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, owin

I have implemented OWIN authentication in my MVC application (I have used Microsoft template when creating new web application on VS2013). Now I notice that (Request.IsAuthenticated) still true after IIS restart.

Comment: Most likely you using cookie based, authentication, so it's not affected by IIS restart

Comment: But when I use (Forms-Based) authentication which is also cookie based then it is affected by IIS restart